# Regex to match first and last word of a sentence only

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a sentence that starts with "hello" and ends with "bye". For example, "hello something bye" should result in a match.

I tried using the regular expression `^hello|[a-z]|bye$`, but it detects everything. I have also tried googling, but I couldn't find a solution for this exact case.

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: And what is your language? Don't spam tags without reason.

Comment: @markalex Python

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am looking for regex which will match for hello ________________ ____ __ ________ ______ ____ bye

Comment: Any sentence that starts with hello and ends with bye

Comment: As your question is not entirely clear, could you please confirm whether you intend to conduct a search for all the sentences that begin with "hello" and end with "bye", as you mentioned in your last comment?

Comment: "_hello something bye_" is not a sentence - it misses punctuation at the end. Just like your entire text in the question. Without that you have/want a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

```
^hello\b.*\bbye$
```

Explanation:

- ^ matches the start of the string (sentence)
- hello matches the literal word "hello"
- .* matches any character (except for newline) zero or more times
- \b matches a word boundary (to ensure that "bye" is a whole word, not
  just a substring)
- bye matches the literal word "bye"
- $ matches the end of the string (sentence)

Comment: That's a good point. It's added.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you could use the regex pattern `^\w+|\w+$`, which would only match words at the beginning or end.  Assuming your actual language be Python, we can try:

```py
inp = "hello something bye"
matches = re.findall(r'^\w+|\w+$', inp)
print(matches)  # ['hello', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it seems that you want to match all instances of the specified pattern. In order to achieve this, you can use something like this:

```py
import re

text = "irrelevant sentence hello first sentence bye irrelevant sentence hello second sentence bye " \
       "irrelevant sentence hello third sentence bye irrelevant sentence"

regex = r"(?:^|\s)(hello\s.*?bye)(?=\s|$)"

matches = re.findall(regex, text)

if matches:
    print("Matches found:", matches)
else:
    print("Matches not found.")
```

Output:

```
Matches found: ['hello first sentence bye', 'hello second sentence bye', 'hello third sentence bye']
```